# Spring Boot, Gradle, and Visual Studio Code - Gradle bootRun Task Not Working Correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to use VS Code for my Spring Boot MVC Java application. I am using the Gradle build tool. I have installed the [Java Language Support extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) from RedHat. Whenever I attempt to run my application using 'gradle bootRun' it never appears to stop executing buts stops at 75%.

[image]

Furthermore, whenever I stop the task  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), I received a message

> the terminal process terminated with exit code: 2.

I have included Spring Boot's development tools as a dependency, but the application does not appear to either restart or reload. I have tried using the `Force Java Recompilation` command provided by the Java extension, but without success.

Has anyone been able to get Spring Boot, Gradle, and VS code to work well together?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have included my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


plugins {
  id "org.kravemir.gradle.sass" version "1.2.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.midamcorp'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 10

task ts(type:Exec) {
workingDir "./"
  commandLine  'cmd', '/c', 'tscCompile.bat'    
}

bootRun {
  args = ["--spring.profiles.active=dev" ]
}
sass {
    main {
        srcDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/sass")
        outDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/static/css")
        exclude = "**/_*.scss"
        minify = true

    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.4')
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180725.0427'

    compile('com.github.mkopylec:recaptcha-spring-boot-starter:2.2.0')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is expected and I think `bootRun` is working correctly. Looking at the screenshot it certainly seems to have successfully started your web application.

The percentage that Gradle shows (75% in this case) is the progress for the whole build. For example, if the build is going to run 4 tasks and `bootRun` is the 4th task, the build will be 75% complete when the `bootRun` task is invoked as 3 out of 4 tasks have completed. The `bootRun` task doesn't end because it's hosting a web application and, therefore, will run indefinitely. This means that Gradle continues to show that the build is 75% complete as, from Gradle's perspective, the final task has not completed.

You may be able to configure your `bootRun` task with `ignoreExitValue = true` so that Gradle does not complain when you stop your web application with `CTRL+C`

Comment: Thanks. I never could seem to get the restart or live reload to work with the Gradle command (maybe that is expected)? In case it helps someone else, Spring Boot's restart and live reload features actually work quite well with the debugger included in the Java extension pack (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack). Coming from Eclipse, I was skeptical that Boot's dev tools would work so smoothly with VS code (which is why I was trying to use Gradle), but they did. Maybe not quite as well as they did with Eclipse, but better than expected. Thanks.